# How long does it take to a local perturbation to propagate along a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, time-evolution, epr-experiment

Imagine to have a one-dimensional system in its ground state, and to apply a local perturbation at one edge of the system. 
How does the system evolve after being perturbed? More specifically, how long does it takes to the perturbation to propagate from one edge of the system to the other? What is the correct theoretical framework to attack the problem?

Let me illustrate this problem with an example. 
Suppose that I have a ferromagnetic one-dimensional chain (Ising-like for simplicity) of $N$ spins. The Hamiltonian:
$$
H=-\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i \sigma_{i+1}
$$

The groundstate of the system is doubly degenerate: there are two eigenstates which minimize the energy, namely $|1\rangle=|\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow...\rangle $ and $|2\rangle=|\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow...\rangle $  (all spins are parallel to one fixed direction) with energy $E_1=E_2=-(N-1)$. 
At the initial time $t=0$ the system is in its groundstate $|1\rangle=|\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow...\rangle $  and at $t>0$ a finite magnetic field is switched on at one edge of the chain in the form:
$$
H'=-\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i \sigma_{i+1}+h\sigma_1
$$
The groundstate of the Hamiltonian $H'$ is not degenerate anymore, in fact one has that
$$
E_1=-(N-1)+h, \qquad
E_2=-(N-1)-h,
$$
and therefore the groundstate is the eigenstate $|2\rangle$ while the state $|1\rangle$ is an excited state with energy $E_2=2h+E_1$.

Intuitively, this perturbation will flip the spin at the edge of the chain, and consequently induce a spin-flip on contiguous spins, and finally flip the whole ferromagnetic chain such that the spins and the magnetic field at one edge are parallel. Roughly speaking, a perturbation at one edge of the chain will propagate along the whole chain reaching the opposite edge at the time $t=\Delta t$.
Therefore the perturbation will make the system decay from the excited state $|1\rangle$ to the groundstate $|2\rangle$.

How can I estimate the time $\Delta t $ needed for the spin-flip perturbation to propagate to the other edge of the chain?

One can naively think that the time needed is related via the energy-time uncertainity relation with the energy of the excited state, and therefore conclude that
$\Delta t\propto 1/(2h)$. 
However this conclusion is wrong, since it is clearly in contradiction with known physical laws (a sort of EPR paradox). 
The value $\Delta t\propto 1/(2h)$ in fact does not depend on the length of the chain
and therefore will allow a transfer of information between the two edges of the chain at superluminal speed if the chain is long enough.

How can one correctly determine the time $\Delta t$ needed for a perturbation to propagate from one edge to the other edge of the chain?

Or more generally:
How I can describe the propagation of such perturbation along the chain?

Comment: You may want to check out Lieb-Robinson bounds, which roughly says there is a "light cone" for local perturbations to propagate in a quantum system. A good introduction is Hastings's lecture note http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5137

Comment: Note that there is no reason to rule out superluminal signalling if you are studying a non-relativistic Hamiltonian. (Of course, the non-relativistic Hamiltonian will not be valid in the first place, but that's a different question.)

Comment: Also, note that your Ising model is not a good example, since a spin flip will actually *not* propagate under the Hamiltonian dynamics.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Ok if you start with a non-relativistic Hamiltonian, the superluminal transmission cannot be ruled out. However, I think that my naive guess $\Delta t\propto 1/(2h)$ is still not correct because it does not depend on the number of lattice sites. Regarding the Ising Hamiltonian. There is no propagation because the two states I have written are eigenstates of the perturbed Hamiltonian. However it is reasonable to assume that the system will decay at some point (e.g., interacting thermodynamically with an external bath) and flip the magnetization.

Comment: @MengCheng I should read those lecture notes more carefully, but it seems to me that they provide only some lower bounds and not a theoretical framework to derive the propagation time given a specific Hamiltonian

Comment: Indeed, your guess is not correct. For Hamiltonian evolution, Lieb-Robinson bounds tell you that there is an upper bound to the propagation speed -- the Lieb-Robinson velocity -- which is proportional to the interaction strength.  (It is similar to a "speed of sound" in a classical mass-and-springs chain.) -- If you want an example with propagation, just choose a perturbation which does not commute with the Hamiltonian, or a different Hamiltonian.  Adding in an environment changes the setup (e.g., you have to specifiy the locality notion of the environment, etc.)

Comment: @sintetico LR-bounds provide an *upper* bound. But you are right, they do not give the actual speed for a specific perturbation. For a specific scenario, you will have to integrate the equations of motion (if it is possible).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Can you be more specific? For example if one takes the example in my question, but considers the Heisenberg Hamiltonian instead of the Ising (this should fix the problem of propagation) what would be the equation of motion?

Comment: You have to compute $U(t)=\exp[-iHt]$ and see how your system evolves under this equation, and when you will see a signal $\ell$ sites away. That's generally not an easy task. For the Heisenberg Hamiltonian, you might be able to use the Bethe ansatz. But there is no general procedure to do so. That's why it is great that we have Lieb-Robinson bounds, which provide a *general* speed limit for quantum spin systems!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch If I time-evolve the Ising system in my example with the time-evolution operator I actually obtain no evolution: the excited state does not decay to the groundstate. Is this physical?

Comment: If your system is isolated: yes. Is an isolated system physical? Most of the times, no (but this depends on the time scale you consider).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Ok so maybe this is the point. How can I estimate my $\Delta t$ for a non-isolated system, e.g., coupled with an external bath?

Comment: As I said, it depends on your bath. You are asking for too much. For the very least, you have to provide *far* more information, namely an exact model for the bath. But even then, you will likely not be able to easily get the *exact* velocity.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I just wanted to figure out if there is a standard way to answer these kind of questions. I don't have a specific model in my mind (it is of course not a homework question). I think that anyway you helped me to understand some basic facts. Perhaps I will come with another question here when I have more clear ideas.

Comment: Short answer: The standard way are Lieb-Robinson bounds. -- Also note that if you couple your system to a bath, generically you expect that information does not propagate at all over larger distances as it will be absorbed by the environment.

Comment: A small note: Your instant switcing on of time dependent potential is proportional to Heaviside step function. This means that it has all the frequencies in its spectrum (1/omega). In linear regime, you can Fourier transform the response, and you will get the response on an individual frequency, which will make the analysis easier.

Comment: Maybe somebody should condense the comments into a short answer? I think this is a valid question and the answer is already here...

Comment: @Martin I obviously support your suggestion